# Java ReplaceAll Regular Expression With Exclusions

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to replace all instances of sentence terminators such as '.', '?', and '!', but I do not want to replace strings like "dr." and "mr.".

I have tried the following:

`text = text.replaceAll("(?![mr|mrs|ms|dr])(\\s*[\\.\\?\\!]\\s*)", "\n");`

...but that does not seem to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**: After the feedback here and a bit of tweeking this is the working solution to my problem.

```
private String convertText(String text) {
  text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
  text = text.replaceAll("[\n\r\\(\\)\"\\,\\:]", "");
  text = text.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!dr|mr|mrs|ms|jr|sr|\\s\\w)(\\s*[\\.\\?\\!\\;](?:\\s+|$))","\r\n");
  return text.trim();
}
```

The code will extract all* compound and single sentences from an excerpt of text, removing all punctuation and extraneous white-space.
**There are some exceptions...*

Comment: Try removing the brackets, `[]`, from around the list of exceptions: `(?!mr|mrs|ms|dr)`. They stand for "character set", not "full strings" as you're using them. Don't know if it will entirely solve your problem, but it's worth a start

Comment: There's several problems with trying to do that though. How are you going to handle sequences like `J. H. Ronaldo says that the train is running on time.... Is he right?`.

Comment: @Anthill, I have added support for ignoring single characters that precede a period. Is this the correct way of is there an even easier method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use negative lookbehind instead of negative lookahead like this

```
String x = "dr. house.";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll("(?<!mr|mrs|ms|dr)(\\s*[\\.\\?\\!]\\s*)","\n"));
```

Also the list of `mr/dr/ms/mrs` should not be inside character classes.

Comment: I was so close, I remember negative look-behinds vaguely. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to have a complete list of the letter combinations which are allowed to precede `.`.  Then, you can replace `dr.` and `mr.` (and any other allowed combos) with something unique like `dr28dsj458sj` and `mr28dsj458sj`.  Ideally you should check that your temp substitute value exists nowhere else in the document.  Then go through and remove all your sentence terminators, then go through again and replace the occurrences of `28dsj458sj` with `.` again.

Comment: I like this hacky workaround, but it may slow down performance. The negative look-behind was what I was going for. Thanks for your time.